# When Can I Conclude Two Algebras are Isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

First, $R$ is a commutative ring with unit.  I have two $R$-algebras, $A$ and $B$.  I have an isomorphism
$$
A\otimes_R\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow B\otimes_R\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Is there a theorem that says when I can conclude that $A\cong B$?  What if everything is free?

Comment: So $\mathbf Z$ is an $R$-algebra/module somehow?

Comment: As Dylan has noted, you first need that $\mathbb Z$ has an $R$-algebra structure for the tensor to make sense.  That essentially means a homomorphism $R\rightarrow \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Yes, $R$ is augmented.  In my case $R$ is a graded ring with $R_0=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Well if "everything is free" means $A$ and $B$ are free $R$ modules, then $A\otimes_R \mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ and likewise for $B\otimes_R\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure you want that to happen. (?)

Comment: The short answer is: No, there is no such theorem. The long answer will be given if you reveal the *real* problem you are working on to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R = \mathbb Z[t]$, $R\to \mathbb Z$ the augmentation $t\mapsto 0$, $A = R$ and $B = \mathbb Z[t, (1-t)^{-1} ]$. The $A\otimes_R \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z = B\otimes_R \mathbb Z$. But $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic.

By tensoring with $\mathbb Z$, we evaluated at $0$ so we can't see what happens at $1$: we inverted $1-t$.

Comment: This is a good counterexample.  I had to refine my conditions to obtain a proof.